# IP Helper Library GetIfTable function failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a Worklight Mobile application in version 5.0.6. When I build my application or preview it, I get an error message that says 'Worklight application builder' has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during "Worklight application builder".  Clicking on the Details button reveals An internal error occurred during "Worklight application builder". IP Helper Library GetIfTable function failed.

The error occurs about 2/5 times I build my application.

Does anyone know how to rectify this issue?

Other notes: I upgraded to 5.0.6 from 5.0.5. The error has occurred with both versions.

Exception Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.Error: IP Helper Library GetIfTable function failed
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getAll(Native Method)
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.common.util.GeneralUtil.scanAllIPv4Interfaces(GeneralUtil.java:598)
    at com.worklight.common.util.GeneralUtil.scanIPAddresses(GeneralUtil.java:527)
    at com.worklight.common.util.GeneralUtil.getIPscanResults(GeneralUtil.java:621)
    at com.worklight.builder.config.BuildConfiguration$Builder.setWorklightServerHost(BuildConfiguration.java:384)
    at com.worklight.builder.config.BuildConfiguration$Builder.deriveParameters(BuildConfiguration.java:286)
    at com.worklight.builder.config.BuildConfiguration$Builder.<init>(BuildConfiguration.java:276)
    at com.worklight.builder.ApplicationBuilder.init(ApplicationBuilder.java:105)
    at com.worklight.builder.ApplicationBuilder.build(ApplicationBuilder.java:80)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.build.apps.WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.buildApplication(WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.java:298)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.build.apps.WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.runInWorkspace(WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: Can you add more of the log message and the stacktrace?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Juno and Java 1.7.0_07

Comment: I edited my first response and added the exception stack trace. Any ideas?

Comment: I resolved my own issue.  I had two installs of Java that were conflicting.  So, I uninstalled both versions, reinstalled the newest version of Java. Just to be on the safe side, I went ahead and uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled it with the Worklight plugin and ADT Plugin.  Everything is working correctly now.

Comment: @JulieRedfoot, can you please write your comment as an Answer to this question, and mark it Answered? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resolved my own issue. I had two installs of Java that were conflicting. So, I uninstalled both versions, reinstalled the newest version of Java. Just to be on the safe side, I went ahead and uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled it with the Worklight plugin and ADT Plugin. Everything is working correctly now.

Comment: I had the same error message in another JGroups based project with IBM J9 JVM 2.4 (Java 1.6.0). Changing the JVM to Oracle 1.6.0_37 solved the issue. Thus I think its a JVM specific issue.